# Dynamic on the fly compile

Tags: python, cython, on-the-fly

I have individual Functions (from user input) for plots (x^2, e^x, x, ...) and I would compute the coordinates in cython.
I created with exec a individual function in Python code yet, but thats to slow for me.

I tried to generate individual .pyx files and compile them to .pyd files (on Windows).

This is my way to generate the individual .pyx file and compile them. The generating works fine, but I only can compile them when I hadn't imported the cython module from the .pyd file in the main script. if I compile it and then import the module in my main class, it works fine, but once imported, I can't compile it anymore. (the file is for testing, no x or y values get stored)

```
def build(function):
    # code for .pyx file
    code = """cpdef long double computeIt(long double count):
    cdef long double i = 0
    cdef long double result = 0
    for i from 0 <= i < count:
        result = _compute(i)
    return result

cpdef long double compute(long double x):
    return _compute(x)
cdef long double _compute(long double x):
    return """ + function
    # end of code

    with open("evalTest.pyx", "w+") as file:
        file.truncate()
        file.write(code)

    os.system("python setup.py build_ext --inplace") # run setup file
```

setup.py file to compile .pyx:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("evalTest.pyx")
)
```

Also I tried to compile it to a temp file and replace the .pyd file with an atomic operation but then i get a "Permission denied" error (also if I run the script as admin).

If i first import the cython module and then try to recompile it, I get:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\onTheFlyCythonCompile\evalTest.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe'
>   failed with exit status 1104

I think the interpreter holds the module and I can't access it but I don't know if thats right. I also tried to unlink the file.

Any Suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the `setup.py` file?

Comment: the setup.py file compiles a .pyx file (cython code) to a .pyd from which you can import modules in normal python programs

Comment: `Cython.Inline`?

Comment: I tried to use it but i can't compile functions and i would execute it as a function that i compile only once the function change

Comment: Fair enough - the issue when I test `Cython,inline` is that you can't use `cdef` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct the the interpreter is holding on to the pyd.  To my knowledge it is effectively impossible to unload a c-extension module in a running python interpreter.

Probably the best way to handle this is a randomized / hashed / some other kind of unique filename.  This is what for instance the %%cython magic in jupyter does.

```
In [94]: import cython

In [95]: %load_ext cython

In [96]: %%cython
    ...: def f(a, b):
    ...:     return a + b
# generates ~/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_5a675eece0e27eef1233e0a3e4d811e5.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
```

Might also look at [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) - it's certainly more convenient for on-the-fly generation.

Comment: At moment I read this post, I installed numba :D. With randomized names, you mean, that i give the .pyd file a random(unique) name and import this unique file after every compilation? But then I hold every .pyd file, what consumpt many memory (I think) or does the interpreter only hold a refference?

Comment: @user9443097 I would assume that is the idea. You could probably use python's `uuid` library to generate the random prefixes.

Comment: i can't import a module from a method or class or could I use something other than import?

Comment: I tested numba and it is so much faster if i use big for loops and only 2x slower if I use small loops. Numba is the much easier and I think better choice for me, thank you (But I try the other solution also)

Comment: Ah I can import a module with importlib.import_module() and assign it to an attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `pyximport`

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
Out[13]: (None, <pyximport.pyximport.PyxImporter at 0x101c7c650>)

import computeIt
```

after code change just:

```
reload(computeIt)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have never thought of using pyximport and hadn't knew, that i can reload modules. Works pretty well!